# Swapping to numpy arrays element wise

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `NumPy` arrays `l` and `g`, and I want to swap the elements of `l` that are greater than the corresponding elements in `g`.

for example:

```
l = [0,19,1]
g = [1,17,2]
```

after the operation

```
l = [0,17,1]
g = [1,19,2]
```

the arrays could be multi dimensional. How do I do this efficiently in `NumPy`?

Comment: you could also use `l_after, g_after = np.where(l<g, l, g), np.where(l>g, l, g))` - however I'd say [NPE's option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59423903/10197418) makes it more clear what the code does ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.minimum` and `np.maximum`:

```
l = np.array([0,19,1])
g = np.array([1,17,2])
l, g = np.minimum(l, g), np.maximum(l, g)
```